# How i can program a robot to ask for confirmation before saving the image or document?

Tags: automation, rpa, g1ant

I am already having an image on my desktop with the name ABC.png and using robot I am downloading another image from the web and saving it on my Desktop but before image would have been saved I want the robot to ask "Do you want to replace the existing image?" or simply even whether I want to download the image or not. How i can do that?

```
♥image = ♥environment⟦USERPROFILE⟧\Desktop\ABC.png
file.download https://static.makeuseof.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/PolkaDots2.jpg filename ♥image
image.findrectangles ♥image
dialog ♥result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `file.exists` command. With that, you can check to see if a file with the same name as `♥image` exists in the existing directory.

Here is one way to do it:

```
♥image = ♥environment⟦USERPROFILE⟧\Desktop\ABC.png
file.exists filename ♥image errorcall downloadFile
dialog.ask message ‴File already exists! Do you want to overwrite the file?‴ result ♥response
if ♥response=="yes"
    call downloadFile 
else if ♥response=="no"
    dialog ‴Operation cancelled, File not downloaded!‴
end

procedure downloadFile
    file.download https://static.makeuseof.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/PolkaDots2.jpg filename ♥image
    stop silentmode true
end
```

What this basically does is that it checks to see if a file exists with the `file.exists` command, that command throws an error if the file does not exist. In the `errorcall` argument, we call the `downloadFile` procedure since we know that the file doesn't already exist, so we go ahead and download it. `downloadFile` procedure uses the `stop` command to end the execution of the robot since we don't really want the bot to execute any further code. (Silent mode is set to true since we don't want to display the "Process was broken at line x" dialog box). If the file does exist, then we proceed to the next line (since no error occurred in `file.exists`, `downloadFile` procedure is not called), we open up as dialog box asking for the user whether they want to download and overwrite the file. If the input is "yes", we download and overwrite the file by calling `downloadFile` or simply displaying the message "Operation cancelled, File not downloaded!" in a dialog box.

Comment: But for that, I should already know the name of the file that I am going to download or save. But what if it's a random file that I am downloading and with some default name which already exists in my system.

Comment: Even if the file has some random name on the website, you still set a particular name to the file in the `file.download` command.